# bash string with/without quote and single/double quote

Tags: linux, string, bash

```
$ volume=vol1
$ echo $volume 
vol1

$ volume="vol1"
$ echo $volume 
vol1

$ volume='vol1'
$ echo $volume 
vol1
```

What is the difference between the above in bash scripting?
All are one and same?

Comment: Duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash . Consider to [close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably find the definitive answer on that [wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Short answer: the quote are needed arround `$volume`.

Comment: From the wiki, The basic rule of thumb is that you should double-quote every expansion. This prevents unwanted word splitting and globbing. When in doubt, quote it.  :)